# Woocommerce tag list having specific string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

The code works perfectly for listing WooCommerce product tags, but I want to add a query with it.

I would like to list only product tags that contain a specific String.

```php
<?php
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

$count = count($terms);
echo "found ". $count . " Schools";

?>
<div class="product-tags">
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`WP_Term_Query`](https://medium.com/vunamhung/say-goodbye-to-get-terms-use-wp-term-query-db774df6d9ea) instead of `get_terms`

```php
$keyword = 'tag';

// Args
$args = array(
    'taxonomy'    => 'product_tag',
    'hide_empty'  => false,
    'name__like'  => $keyword,
);

// Term Query
$query = new WP_Term_Query($args);

// Get terms
$get_terms = $query->get_terms();

// Count
$count = count( $get_terms );

echo "found ". $count . " Schools";

// Loop
foreach ( $get_terms as $terms ) {
    echo $terms->name;
}
```

Comment: Working.. but I want to find total no. of rows returned as well.. previously used `$count = count($terms);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'search' or 'name_like' fields in the first argument array, per the wordpress documentation here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

For example, say you want to get all terms where the name contains 'foo'

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'name__like' => '%foo%'
));
```

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work? what did you try? Post code in your question please.

Comment: `<?php $terms = get_terms(array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false, 'name_like' => '%foo%' )); $count = count($terms); echo "found ". $count . " Records"; ?> <div class="product-tags"> <ul> <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?> <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id, 'product_tag' ); ?> " rel="tag"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li> <?php } ?> </ul> </div>`

Comment: Do you actually have any product tags who's name contains the word "foo"? you need to change foo to whatever your query is.

Comment: adding one extra underscore and useing variable solved the issue.. 'name__like' => $string, ... thanks for your support..